# What are the possible values of the Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto configuration and what do they do

Tags: java, hibernate, hbm2ddl

I really want to know more about the update, export and the values that could be given to `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`
I need to know when to use the update and when not? And what is the alternative?

These are changes that could happen over DB:

- new tables
- new columns in old tables
- columns deleted
- data type of a column changed
- a type of a column changed its attributes
- tables dropped
- values of a column changed

In each case what is the best solution?

Answer (score 1237):

From the [community documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl):

> hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto    Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the SessionFactory is created. With create-drop, the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly.
>
> e.g. validate | update | create | create-drop

So the list of possible options are,

- *validate*: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
- *create-only*: database creation will be generated.
- *drop*: database dropping will be generated.
- *update*: update the schema.
- *create*: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
- *create-drop*: drop the schema when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly, typically when the application is stopped.
- *none*: does nothing with the schema, makes no changes to the database

These options seem intended to be developers tools and not to facilitate any production level databases, you may want to have a look at the following question; [Hibernate: hbm2ddl.auto=update in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-autoupdate-in-production)

Comment: Just read the hibernate docu ... for valid values, it says: "e.g." ... are there any other valid values?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. They could be misusing e.g., or the values could simply be undocumented.

Comment: I think it says "e.g." because it's just a community documentation, if someone's interested in all the possible values, it can be found in Hibernate's javadoc. (And yes, only those four options are present)

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.html#HBM2DDL_AUTO

Comment: validate says validate the schema , what exactly does it mean ??

Comment: Hi - afaik I know, and saw throught usage, "validate" means just that - it will compare the database schema against your declared (or annotated) datalayer (Hibernate), and complain (or break?) if things do not match. But it won't make any changes to the database itself.

Comment: A thing that i've had noticed is that if I change the column type into the model, the same column on database is not changed with **update**

Comment: 'empty string' can also be used.

Comment: You can also use 'aardvark', or 'pigeon' or any other word, if you want hibernate to do nothing. Not that I would recommend that of course!

Comment: Is there any option that says, just create if don't exist, don't update, don't drop :(

Comment: A small addition to the create-drop option. If this option is used it does not drop the whole schema instead it drops the tables whose mappings are available while running this. For example if a database with Schema S has A, B, C tables and java code has mappings for A and B only then Hibernate will not drop the table C.

Comment: @Aditya create-drop does not drop the "Schema" **and** does not create it.

Comment: Note that create-drop do not drop database just closing session but the **Session Factory**.

Comment: My experience contradicts with @Ward's comment: when I use a value like "no_validation", I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized legacy `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` value : no_validation
```

Answer (score 213):

There's also the value of [`none`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl) to disable it entirely.

Comment: This is actually quite useful since Hibernate’s schema validation sometimes fails for perfectly valid schemas.

Comment: I was just about to ask for something like this. My intention is to reduce startup time.

Comment: The 'none' value is very useful also when you want to use dynamic/programmatic configuration of Hibernate; any other value would cause an error when the application is started.

Comment: **'empty string' is better than 'none'**. To use 'none', you will receive warning message: org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory  - Unrecognized value for "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto": none

Comment: I've patched it. Added "none" as an explicitly valid constant.

Comment: I like "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=potato" over others http://stackoverflow.com/a/15810379/838444

Comment: Look for log "Unrecognized hbm2ddl_auto value : none.  Supported values include create, create-drop, update, and validate.  Ignoring". :D

Answer (score 172):

The configuration property is called `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`

In our development environment we set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop` to drop and create a clean database each time we deploy, so that our database is in a known state.

In theory, you can set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` to update your database with changes to your model, but I would not trust that on a production database. An earlier version of the documentation said that this was experimental, at least; I do not know the current status.

Therefore, for our production database, do not set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` - the default is to make no database changes. Instead, we manually create an SQL DDL update script that applies changes from one version to the next.

Comment: Actually, per the documentation, create-drop creates the database tables and drops them when the session factory is explicitly closed. It does *not* drop the tables when the session factory is created.

Comment: No, both create-drop and create drop the tables when the sessionfactory is created, then create-drop drops the tables also when sessionfactory is closed. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6752698/1536382

Comment: does making hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop in production can lead to several connection timeout in production ?

Answer (score 110):

First, the possible values for the `hbm2ddl` configuration property are the following ones:

- `none` - No action is performed. The schema will not be generated.
- `create-only` - The database schema will be generated.
- `drop` - The database schema will be dropped.
- `create` - The database schema will be dropped and created afterward.
- `create-drop` - The database schema will be dropped and created afterward. Upon closing the `SessionFactory`, the database schema will be dropped.
- `validate` - The database schema will be validated using the entity mappings.
- `update` - The database schema will be updated by comparing the existing database schema with the entity mappings.

The `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto="update"` is convenient but less flexible if you plan on adding functions or executing some custom scripts.

So, The *most flexible approach* is to use [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/).

However, even if you use Flyway, you can still generate the initial migration script using hbm2ddl.

Comment: `drop` doesn't seem to be a valid option. Which version of hibernate are you referring to?

Comment: It's been a valid option since Hibernate 5.1, which was released in 2016. Check out the [`Action`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5eedda9a467fef44d924f64203023b2345b8415f/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/tool/schema/Action.java#L35) enum for more details. I assume you are using a very old Hibernate version.

Comment: what is the exact difference between validate vs update.

Comment: The answer tells the difference.

Answer (score 52):

I would use [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org) for updating your db. hibernate's schema update feature is really only o.k. for a developer while they are developing new features. In a production situation, the db upgrade needs to be handled more carefully.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-autoupdate-in-production for why you shouldn't use hbm2ddl for production.

Answer (score 51):

Although it is quite an old post but as i did some research on the topic so thought of sharing it.

***hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto***

As per the documentation it can have four valid values:

***create  |  update  |  validate  |  create-drop***

Following is the explanation of the behaviour shown by these value:

- *create* :- create the schema, the data previously present (if there) in the schema is lost
- update:- update the schema with the given values.
- validate:- validate the schema. It makes no change in the DB.
- create-drop:- create the schema with destroying the data previously present(if there). It also drop the database schema when the SessionFactory is closed.

Following are the important points worth noting:

- In case of ***update***, if schema is not present in the DB then the schema is created.
- In case of ***validate***, if schema does not exists in DB, it is not created. Instead, it will throw an error:- `Table not found:<table name>`
- In case of ***create-drop***, schema is not dropped on closing the session. It drops only on closing the SessionFactory.
- In case if i give any value to this property(say abc, instead of above four values discussed above) or it is just left blank. It shows following behaviour:

  -If schema is not present in the DB:- It creates the schema

  -If schema is present in the DB:- ***update*** the schema.

Comment: It's indeed a very important point that schema will be created if it doesn't exist, when "update" is used.

Comment: create-drop is contradicted when compare "Explanation of the behaviour" and "Important Points" statements.

Comment: What's the difference between **update** and **empty**?

Answer (score 27):

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` automatically validates and exports DDL to the schema when the sessionFactory is created.

By default, it does not perform any creation or modification automatically on DB. If the user sets one of the below values then it is doing DDL schema changes automatically.

- create - doing creating a schema

  ```
  <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create">
  ```
- update - updating existing schema

  ```
  <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update">
  ```
- validate - validate existing schema

  ```
  <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate">
  ```
- create-drop - create and drop the schema automatically when a session is starts and ends

  ```
  <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop">
  ```

Comment: what about <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"> ?

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to use Strings in your app and are looking for predefined constants have a look at `org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings` class included in the Hibernate JAR, where you'll find a constant for all possible settings. In your case for example:

```
/**
 * Auto export/update schema using hbm2ddl tool. Valid values are <tt>update</tt>,
 * <tt>create</tt>, <tt>create-drop</tt> and <tt>validate</tt>.
 */
String HBM2DDL_AUTO = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
```

Comment: Why is reference to 700+ lines long source file above straight answer with almost 500 vole ups ?

Comment: ... that question doesnt make any sense. Why are there things? Why am i even here?

Answer (score 10):

- `validate`: validates the schema, no change happens to the database.
- `update`: updates the schema with current execute query.
- `create`: creates new schema every time, and destroys previous data.
- `create-drop`: drops the schema when the application is stopped or SessionFactory is closed explicitly.

Comment: Whats the 'official' documentation reference? - just wondering...

Answer (score 7):

I Think you should have to concentrate on the

```
SchemaExport Class
```

this Class Makes Your Configuration Dynamic 
So it allows you to choose whatever suites you best...

Checkout [[SchemaExport]](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html)

Answer (score 4):

`validate`: It validates the schema and makes no changes to the DB.
Assume you have added a new column in the mapping file and perform the insert operation, it will throw an Exception "missing the XYZ column" because the existing schema is different than the object you are going to insert. If you alter the table by adding that new column manually then perform the Insert operation then it will definitely insert all columns along with the new column to the Table.
Means it doesn't make any changes/alters the existing schema/table.

`update`: it alters the existing table in the database when you perform operation. 
You can add or remove columns with this option of hbm2ddl. 
But if you are going to add a new column that is 'NOT NULL' then it will ignore adding that particular column to the DB. Because the Table must be empty if you want to add a 'NOT NULL' column to the existing table.

Answer (score 3):

**Since 5.0**, you can now find those values in a dedicated `Enum`: [`org.hibernate.boot.SchemaAutoTooling`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/SchemaAutoTooling.html) (enhanced with value `NONE` since 5.2).

Or even better, **since 5.1**, you can also use the [`org.hibernate.tool.schema.Action`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/schema/Action.html) `Enum` which combines JPA 2 and "legacy" Hibernate DDL actions.

**But**, you cannot yet configure a `DataSource` programmatically with this. It would be nicer to use this combined with [`org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings#HBM2DDL_AUTO`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.html#HBM2DDL_AUTO) but the current code expect a `String` value (excerpt taken from [`SessionFactoryBuilderImpl`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.2.2/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/boot/internal/SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java#L711)):

```java
this.schemaAutoTooling = SchemaAutoTooling.interpret( (String) configurationSettings.get( AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO ) );
```

… and internal `enum` values of both [`org.hibernate.boot.SchemaAutoTooling`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.2.2/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/boot/SchemaAutoTooling.java)and [`org.hibernate.tool.schema.Action`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.2.2/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/tool/schema/Action.java) aren't exposed publicly.

Hereunder, a sample programmatic `DataSource` configuration (used in ones of my Spring Boot applications) which use a gambit thanks to `.name().toLowerCase()` but it only works with values without dash (not `create-drop` for instance):

```java
@Bean(name = ENTITY_MANAGER_NAME)
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean internalEntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier(DATA_SOURCE_NAME) DataSource internalDataSource) {

    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO, SchemaAutoTooling.CREATE.name().toLowerCase());
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.DIALECT, H2Dialect.class.getName());

    return builder
            .dataSource(internalDataSource)
            .packages(JpaModelsScanEntry.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class)
            .persistenceUnit(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME)
            .properties(properties)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To whomever searching for default value...

It is written in the source code at version 2.0.5 of spring-boot and 1.1.0 at JpaProperties:

```
    /**
     * DDL mode. This is actually a shortcut for the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"
     * property. Defaults to "create-drop" when using an embedded database and no
     * schema manager was detected. Otherwise, defaults to "none".
     */
    private String ddlAuto;
```

Answer (score 0):

With all above said...
Notice this property is called `dll.auto` and should only control dll operations(create/drop schema/table), I found surprisingly that it has to do with dml, too: only `update` will allow insert data, which is dml operation.

Got caught by this when trying to populate data into a in-memory database; only `update` works.