# Hibernate is not auto creating sequencies to database when using auto creating of tables

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, orm, sequence, hbm2ddl

I want to create my database tables automatically with Hibernate and Postgresql, but I get errors about sequences. Is it possible to auto create sequences too with Hibernate, or do I have generate sequences manually?

Example of my entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint( columnNames =  { "id" }) })
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_EXAMPLE_ID", sequenceName="example_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
public class Example {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_EXAMPLE_ID")
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String g
}
```

Hibernate config:

```
hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Exceptions:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "example_id_seq" does not exist
```

Comment: Your mapping seems right. Just for curiosity: does Postgre support sequence ?

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping seems correct and I suggest activating logging of the following category to see what is happening exactly:

> - `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl`: Log all SQL DDL statements as they are executed

Set it to `DEBUG` and check the DDL statements (maybe update the question with the relevant parts).

PS: An `allocationSize=1` is not very wise, using the default would be better. But that's unrelated.

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [3.5. Logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging)

Comment: I didn't see anything even loggin had been turned on.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable automatic schema creation in `application.properties` as described in [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html):

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create
```

or when using Spring:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
```

But the general recommendation is **not to use this in production**, see [Hibernate: hbm2ddl.auto=update in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-production)

Use database schema migration tools like [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) or [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Applicable for Postgres

```
<hibernate-mapping>

  <!-- ... -->

  <database-object>
    <create>CREATE SEQUENCE my_sequence</create>
    <drop>DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS my_sequence</drop>
  </database-object>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score -2):

-We cant create sequences by using hbm2ddl property
-we can create any number of tables any no of times but not sequence

sequence is db specific  and we have to create our selves sequence in db