# Recreating table structure with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, derby

This is a simply one - how can I make my DB (I am using Derby) to commit the changes in entity(I mean changing the column name, constraints, etc)? Because I've discovered when I change something in entity atributes, my DB still remains the same. I am also using Netbeans if there is any functionality for this.

I am now aware of hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto, but I am looking for something similar(e.g. I don't want to drop date during structure changes from entity to DB)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify your persistence provider, but I'll assume hibernate; you can use the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` configuration parameter to tell hibernate to recreate the tables. See [this SO question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689769/320220). Note that you **should not** use this in production; [see this SO question for those details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/221422/320220).

Comment: No, I am using EclipseLink. Well after some googling, I see that I should set eclipselink.ddl-generation to drop-and-create-tables, but I will also lose my data, so is there any other way for doing this?

Comment: I haven't used EclipseLink; in hibernate you can set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `update`, as discussed in the second link, but I've never tried this. This isn't safe; if you need it for test/development purposes, you can try using DBUnit; there's a tutorial in [this blog post](http://www.antoniogoncalves.org/xwiki/bin/view/Article/TestingJPA#HAddingDbUnit).