# How can I make Hibernate put comments on the tables/fields it creates

Tags: hibernate, documentation, annotations, ddl

I would like Hibernate, when generating DDL, to include comments from my java source. I'd be happy to do this as an annotation, or as a javadoc tag.

IOW:
I'd like to be able to go

```
@Entity
@DDLComment "This entity is cool"
class Foo {
  @DDLComment "But this field is kinda lame"
  int lame_o_rama;
```

And (in oracle), hibernate should generate

```
CREATE TABLE FOO ( LAME_O_RAMA number };
COMMENT ON FOO IS 'This entity is cool';
COMMENT ON FOO.LAME_O_RAMA 'But this field is kinda lame';
```

Is there a annotation, doc tag, config option, etc etc, to do this?

Comment: There has been a discussion on this topic, but as it appears nothing happened after that: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=942748

Answer (score 0):

from hibernate docs ...

> SchemaExport is a Hibernate utility which generates DDL from your
>   mapping files. The generated schema includes referential integrity
>   constraints, primary and foreign keys, for entity and collection
>   tables. It also creates tables and sequences for mapped identifier
>   generators.

[doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html_single/)

how ever the schemaexport utility is to help with the development, no for maintenance or production.
[Hibernate: hbm2ddl.auto=update in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-production)