# HIbernate creating database table

Tags: java, hibernate

I am in the process of learning JPA  - Hibernate.

I am following this [article](http://uaihebert.com/?p=57)
In Dog.java it is mentioned as `@Table(name = "dog")`.
 In `persistence.xml` I have the following

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

Does this creates table dog in database? I have not created table Dog in database. So in production environment this could be dangerous though. In such scenarios what should be ideal value for  `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's dangerous in all senses, your application user should not have DDL permissions (alter table, create tables) your application user should only do DML (SELECT, INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE, etc)

Comment: If application user should do only DML, then what should be the value for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`? Is it `none`? Thanks

Comment: just don't add it, comment it out. Reason behind is someone can manipulate that connection in order to drop a table or something. more secure if you don't manipulate with same user.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does create the new table **every** time that your app is deployed. Better to use:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
```

if you already have data in place.

Here are the *possible* options:

- validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
- update: update the schema.
- create: creates the schema, destroying previous data(!)
- create-drop: drop the schema at the end of the session(!)

Answer (score 1):

**Do not set `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>` in production**, because whenever you restart the server, all tables will be deleted and newly created again. You can make use of this property(`hibernate feature`) if you are migrating from one database to another.

If you want to set then set `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>` in development(not in production). This will update the schema if there are any changes you have made in `pojo classes`(annotations).

Also check : [Hibernate: hbm2ddl.auto=update in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-production)

[Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto possible values and what they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-question-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do)

Answer (score 1):

Set it to "none" in a production environment.