# Enable hbm2ddl.keywords=auto-quote in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: mysql, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, quotes

I have made a tiny software tool that allows me to display or run SQL generated from NHibernate. I made this because [hbm2ddl.auto is not recommended for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-production).

I have one problem: when I generate the SQL I always get the infamous `Index` column unquoted, because I need `.AsList()` mappings. This prevents me to run the SQL.

In theory, if I had an XML configuration of NHibernate I could use `hbm2ddl.keywords` tag, but unfortunately since my tool is designed as a DBA-supporting tool for multiple environments, I must use a programmatic approach.

My approach (redundant) is the following:

```
private static Configuration BuildNHConfig(string connectionString, DbType dbType, out Dialect requiredDialect)
    {
        IPersistenceConfigurer persistenceConfigurer;

        switch (dbType)
        {
            case DbType.MySQL:
                {
                    persistenceConfigurer =
                        MySQLConfiguration
                        .Standard
                        .Dialect<MySQL5Dialect>()
                        .Driver<MySqlDataDriver>()
                        .FormatSql()
                        .ShowSql()
                        .ConnectionString(connectionString);

                    requiredDialect = new MySQL5Dialect();
                    break;
                }
            case DbType.MsSqlAzure:
                {
                    persistenceConfigurer = MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                        .Dialect<MsSqlAzure2008Dialect>()
                        .Driver<SqlClientDriver>()
                        .FormatSql()
                        .ShowSql()
                        .ConnectionString(connectionString);

                    requiredDialect = new MsSqlAzure2008Dialect();
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
        }


        FluentConfiguration fc = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(persistenceConfigurer)
            .ExposeConfiguration(
                cfg => cfg.SetProperty("hbm2ddl.keywords", "keywords")
                            .SetProperty("hbm2ddl.auto", "none"))
            .Mappings(
            m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<NHibernateFactory>());
        Configuration ret = fc.BuildConfiguration();
        SchemaMetadataUpdater.QuoteTableAndColumns(ret);
        return ret;


    }

...

public static void GenerateSql(MainWindowViewModel viewModel)
    {
        Dialect requiredDialect;
        Configuration cfg = BuildNHConfig(viewModel.ConnectionString, viewModel.DbType.Value, out requiredDialect);

        StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (string sqlLine in cfg.GenerateSchemaCreationScript(requiredDialect))
            sqlBuilder.AppendLine(sqlLine);

        viewModel.Sql = sqlBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Explanation: when I want to set the `ViewModel`'s SQL to display on a TextBox (yea, this is WPF) I initialize the configuration programmatically with connection string given in `ViewModel` and choose the dialect/provider accordingly. When I `Fluently` `Configure` NHibernate I both set `hbm2ddl.keywords` (tried both `auto-quote` and `keywords`, this being the default) and, following [this blog post](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.it/2009/06/auto-quote-tablecolumn-names.html), I also use the `SchemaMetadataUpdater`.

The result is that I'm always presented with SQL like

```
create table `OrderHistoryEvent` (Id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, EventType VARCHAR(255) not null, EventTime DATETIME not null, EntityType VARCHAR(255), Comments VARCHAR(255), Order_id VARCHAR(255), Index INTEGER, primary key (Id))
```

where the guilty `Index` column is not quoted.

**The question is**: given a programmatic and fluent configuration of NHibernate, how do I tell NHibernate to quote any reserved word in the SQL exported by `GenerateSchemaCreationScript`?

Comment: I was thinking about using a convention. Any column named Index is renamed to... ListIndex for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround: when I generate the update script (the one that runs with `hbm2ddl.auto=update`) the script is correctly quoted.

The [infamous Index column](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fluent-nhibernate/HOmPEjpucIk) has been already discussed and from my findings it's hardcoded in FNH (`ToManyBase.cs`, method `public T AsList()`).

Since the update script is a perfectly working creational script on an empty database, changing the code to generate an update script on an empty DB should equal generating a creational script.

This happens only because I want to generate the script on my own. There is probably a bug in NHibernate that only activates when you call `GenerateSchemaCreationScript` and not when you let your `SessionFactory` build the DB for you