# Spring boot ddl auto generator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`, but when application restarted, all tables drops and creates again. Is there some way to avoiding re-creation for already existing tables?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

[hibernate.ddl-auto](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional) should usually not be used in production.

Comment: @IllSc lots of discussion here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-production

Comment: WHY should not be used in production?

Comment: Check the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Can't find this words

Answer (score 108):

The list of option which is used in the spring boot are

- **validate:** validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
- **update:** update the schema.
- **create:** creates the schema, destroying previous data.
- **create-drop:** drop the schema at the end of the session
- **none:** is all other cases.

So for avoiding the data lose you use update