# Postgresql with spring boot - database is empty whenever I start the application

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I'm learning Spring Boot and I've created a simple application where I'm connecting to a postgresql database and I perform simple insert/update/delete operations. Everything works fine, but the rows I add on the database does not persist on the DB if I stop the application. Do I have to specify a kind of commit somewhere?
This is the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=*pass*
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change to:

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

read: [Spring boot ddl auto generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113154/spring-boot-ddl-auto-generator)