# How to generate database structure in Hibernate automatically only when I explicitly request this?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In Hibernate there is `ddl-auto` feature which allows us to automatically ensure that database structure matches entities structure.

According to [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36341312/11400950) there is next options available:

- validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
- update: update the schema.
- create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
- create-drop: drop the schema at the end of the session
- none: is all other cases.

`But I want this feature to work next way:

1. When I explicitly ask to ensure that database structure matches entity structure (for example with console command like `mvn hibernate:ddl-update`) update the schema.
2. If I don't explicitly ask to modify database then DO NOTHING

How I can achieve this behavior of `ddl-auto`?

Comment: Is there any reason that you want it done via hibernate rather than a sql script?

Comment: If I use SQL script then I will need to describe my models structure twice: first time in entity classes, second time in SQL script. I'm lazy, so I want to describe my models structure once in entity classes and then generate database structure from entity classes.