# Hibernate/JPA: storing constants in entity class?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, constants, hibernate-mapping

I work on remote project and found interesting record in log:

```
2015-12-26 00:28:30,835 DEBUG org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate
  Caller+0   at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:251)
  => alter table bail add column monthName tinyblob
```

with logging set to:

```
<logger level="trace" name="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl"/>
```

when try to identify what happen to:

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

on first run from backup.

When I have seen *Bail.java* source I am surprised:

```
String[] monthName = {"Января", "Февраля",
        "Марта", "Апреля", "Мая", "Июня", "Июля",
        "Августа", "Сентября", "Октября", "Ноября",
        "Декабря"
};
```

So this is constant field!

Is it right to store constants declaration in entity class in term of JPA / Hibernate?

How should I mark constant so it wouldn't be entity property?

I think that `static` keyword do the job and I think about refactoring code to:

```
public static final String[] monthName = 
    Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(
        "Января", "Февраля", "Марта", "Апреля", "Мая", "Июня", "Июля",
        "Августа", "Сентября", "Октября", "Ноября", "Декабря"
));
```

Because production version deployed with `hbm2ddl.auto=update` I think I should warn DBA to remove unnecessary `monthName` column.

Comment: static? transient? @Transient. Ample ways. If something is a constant it should be static anyway ... but then that is nothing to do with JPA, and everything to do with Java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All properties are persisted by default as if they were marked with the [`@Basic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Basic.html) annotation.

To avoid a field from being persisted you have the following options:

- you can mark it with [`@Transient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html)
- you can make it a `static final` field, but then you might want to move it to a constants class utilities anyway
- the best approach is to use the Java 8 `java.time.Month` and then internationalize the month name so you can support multiple languages in the UI, while storing a universal name in the DB.

Comment: `final` keyword is natural for constants. Is it enough only `static` to avoid filed be persisted? I think so but afraid that there is something hidden...

Comment: You can use static and then Hibernate will not persist those fields.

Comment: Using Java 17 with Spring Boot JDBC I still get `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "column_name" of relation "table_name" does not exist` with a `static final` field.

Comment: @MarcoLackovic This question is about JPA and Hibernate. If you are using Spring Boot JDBC, then this question and answer are not going to help you since you are using a different data access library.

Comment: @VladMihalcea thanks, I will try to find a solution elsewhere then: for the moment I simply moved the constant to a service class.