# Liquibase hibernate tables update from java code

Tags: java, hibernate, liquibase

Could you please give me some examples of how to update database tables from java code using hibernate entity classes and liquibase.

Something like this, but for annotated classes

```
Connection connection = null;

try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dvdrental", "postgres", "admin");
    Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
    Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("C:/changelog.xml", new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), database);
    liquibase.update(new Contexts());
} catch (SQLException | LiquibaseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (connection != null) {
        try {
            connection.rollback();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because of liquibase knows nothing about hibernate.

But you can update database with hibernate by set property

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`

or you can generate ddl into file

`java -cp hibernate_classpaths org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport options mapping_files`

with this tool you can export ddl to a file and execute script manually or do it automatically (mapping_files is optional)

P.S: liquibase is developed for declarative markup of updates, not for using with hibernate together

may be this link will be helpful

http://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app

Comment: hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update is bad idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-production.

java -cp hibernate_classpaths org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport options mapping_files - we are developing dynamically extensible, so it's not an option

Comment: may be this link will be helpful

http://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app