# Errors creating multiple database entities in Spring/hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Attempting to make a spring application with multiple databases in spring-boot. MY orm is hibernate and below I have a copy of my application.properties files and my print trace. Thanks for any help in advance:

```
spring.ds_toner.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/toner_stock?useSSL=false
spring.ds_toner.username=toner
spring.ds_toner.password=toner
spring.ds_toner.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.ds_manager.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/toner_manager?useSSL=false
spring.ds_manager.username=toner
spring.ds_manager.password=toner
spring.ds_manager.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.ds_buyer.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/toner_buyer?useSSL=false
spring.ds_buyer.username=toner
spring.ds_buyer.password=toner
spring.ds_buyer.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

Print Trace:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=52449:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/TonerStock/target/classes:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.11/logback-core-1.1.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.24/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.24.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.24/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.24.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.3.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.7/jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.7/jackson-core-2.8.7.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/nz/net/ultraq/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/1.4.0/thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.4.0.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.9/groovy-2.4.9.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.9.Final/hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.21.0-GA/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/classmate-1.3.3.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.13.1.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.24/slf4j-api-1.7.24.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.24/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.24.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.9/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.5.11/tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.5.11/tomcat-juli-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.11.1.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.39/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.2.9.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.9.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.6.6/byte-buddy-1.6.6.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring3/3.0.3.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring3-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/2.1.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.0.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar com.ronone.Application
objc[6848]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10eb834c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1103f14e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.2.RELEASE)

2017-05-11 21:12:08.760  INFO 6848 --- [           main] com.ronone.Application                   : Starting Application on Ronalds-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 6848 (/Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/TonerStock/target/classes started by ronaldpitt in /Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/TonerStock)
2017-05-11 21:12:08.763  INFO 6848 --- [           main] com.ronone.Application                   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-05-11 21:12:09.015  INFO 6848 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@77be656f: startup date [Thu May 11 21:12:09 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-11 21:12:10.645  INFO 6848 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$578c281f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-05-11 21:12:11.075  INFO 6848 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-05-11 21:12:11.108  INFO 6848 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-05-11 21:12:11.110  INFO 6848 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-05-11 21:12:11.267  INFO 6848 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-05-11 21:12:11.267  INFO 6848 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2258 ms
2017-05-11 21:12:11.465  INFO 6848 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-05-11 21:12:11.471  INFO 6848 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-11 21:12:11.472  INFO 6848 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-11 21:12:11.473  INFO 6848 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-11 21:12:11.473  INFO 6848 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-11 21:12:11.532  WARN 6848 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2017-05-11 21:12:11.534  INFO 6848 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-05-11 21:12:11.547  WARN 6848 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
2017-05-11 21:12:11.561  INFO 6848 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-05-11 21:12:11.569 ERROR 6848 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Comment: Please see this [Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902997/multiple-database-with-springhibernatejpa)

Comment: check this if you are looking for java config and not xml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122329/tables-not-getting-created-in-multiple-databases-in-spring-boot-application/43281133#43281133

Comment: Please show your `pom.xml` file

Comment: Please share your pom file and database entity/transaction manager configuration  files

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the exception is

```
Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. 
If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the 
classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular 
profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Spring autoconfiguration is creating only one DataSource and expects properties as

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
```

[spring boot reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html)

You do not set these properties, so spring tries to create a datasource without url, which leads to the exception.

You need to create additional DataSources yourself, you may find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614301/spring-boot-multiple-datasource) helpfull.