# Instantiating a database and running multiple sql scripts for production environment from spring-boot application

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, flyway

I have a spring-boot application which needs to be moved to production. I need to define strategy to instantiate the DB for this which includes creating tables in the Database and adding some default values

I saw spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl feature but this will create/drop each time my application is restarted. Also, i read a bit about flyway but that seems to be a complex DB migration tool and all i have to do is create some tables if not present. Also, i need to be able to control the priority for the different sql scripts that will run.

Is there any simple approach (preferably open source) to run multiple sql scrips from a spring boot application with a defined priority.

Answer (score 0):

You could use update rather than create

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Some other options other than create and update are:

- validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
- update: update the schema.
- create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
- create-drop: drop the schema at the end of the session

Note: But still this is not safe/preferred in production due to various reasons.
[Hibernate: hbm2ddl.auto=update in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-production)

Comment: Ok, so we will not be using this approach. How is flyway for this ?  Is it simple enough to be implemented in a small application. I don't want t get into a situation where the DB part is more complex than the complete application :)