# Hibernate doesn't alter the existing column is that a drawback?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a spring boot application that is connecting to PostgreSQL database. The DAO layer is implemented using `Hibernate` and `JPA` and `auto-ddl` is enabled so that hibernate takes care of creating table

Suddenly today my friend asked me to alter one of the column type `BigInteger` to `String`, then I said which is impossible because that column already filled with data and hibernate will not allow that

Now he is telling it is drawback in hibernate and we also had debate on does companies  alter column definition based on requirement in production?

**Question**

1. Is it really drawback in hibernate?
2. Do IT companies or any organizations frequently alter column definition in production?

Comment: 1. hibernate is it's own drawback. 2. only using a real, tested, migration strategy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should never use `auto-ddl` in [production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-production). It was never intended to be used in production, but for development. The reason why you shouldn't use it is that it might create un-optimal DDL or just damage your data.

The preferred approach to do changes in DB is to create a folder, which would contain all SQL scripts that alter the database structure and store it in version control. The common name is `migrations`. Then you could either manually run these scripts on your database or use tool like [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) (my recommendation) or [liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/).

So how can you make use of `auto-ddl`? For example, you could create a table for your new entity, then take DDL which was used to create it and after applying some adjustments (if necessary) store it in migrations. You can also use **validate** from **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto** to check if your database matches with your entities.

And finally answering your questions:

1. No, it's not a drawback of hibernate, because `auto-ddl` was never intended to do database migrations.
2. Companies never change their databases using utilities like `auto-ddl`. Someone (DBA or developer) prepares migrations script and then it's applied either manually or by migration tool on release.

Comment: Just for the first few words this answer deserves an upvote!! Anyone why uses auto-ddl in "production" doesn't understand what production means.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a drawback of Hibernate, `auto-ddl` is designed to create the schema from the model and not update it.  The reason is because, as you've found yourself, this is rarely straightforward and may require some "massaging" of the data.

I wouldn't say it's a common practise to change data types in production systems, but it's certainly a valid scenario to find oneself in.  In my years I've had to do this a handful of times, although it's usually something as trivial as increasing the size of a `varchar` or changing from `date` to a `datetime`.  Changing from a `BigInteger` to a `String` seems a little unusual and I would question how you've got to that position, it may indicate a problem with the design.

Either way, the solution is to change the data type in the database, which shouldn't be a problem, and then change the `Hibernate` mapping to reflect this change.