# Error when trying to add a new boolean column to a table which already has data

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I tried adding a new attribute to an entity Customer which already has data stored in the database:

```
private boolean isArchived;
```

This gives me the following error when i start spring and try to update the tables:

```
Error executing DDL "alter table customer add column is_archived boolean not null" via JDBC Statement
```

Is that because he tries to initialize `isArchived` with null for the already existing rows and the primitive type cant be null? Is there a way to just initialize them with false instead or do i have to use `Boolean` instead of `boolean` to allow null values(which i would like not to allow)?

Comment: I think it's related to config which related to updating schema `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create`

Comment: Fast tip: try to **not use** ddl-auto on production: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-production/36317695#36317695

Answer (score 8):

It's because existing rows can't have null values, with the new non-null column. The way to do is to provide a default value. You can do it like below:

```
@Column(nullable=false, columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE")
private boolean isArchived;
```

Comment: So that way every value was default false(as it should be), but it was still nullable. So `nullable = false` didnt do anything.

Comment: How do you generate the schema? If using hibernate, then it should be non-null at schema level. If you are using hibernate in pre-existing schema, then this annotation is hint for the persistent provider for bean validation, but at db level, it won't change anything. @M.Dietz

Answer (score 3):

Existing rows cannot have null values so you can set the default value with one of the following options:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="tinyint(1) default 0")
private boolean isArchived;

private boolean isArchived = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is that because he tries to initialize isArchived with null for the already existing rows and the primitive type cant be null?

No, it's because apparently, the database already has `NULL` values for some rows, and so the RDBMS cannot enforce the constraint you're trying to implicitly create by using a primitive type.

The solution is, simply, to apply a db migration to existing data that will populate the `is_archived` column for the problematic rows *before* the DDL gets executed.