# Hibernate and SQLite : Set unique constraint on creation

Tags: java, sqlite, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I'm using Hibernate to create SQLite tables.

I have a table as such

```kotlin
@Entity 
class Person(

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    val name: String,

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Int? = null,
)
```

I see that when the database is created, the `unique` constraint is added later on via an ALTER request

```
Hibernate: create table Person (id  integer, name varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table Person add constraint UK_is4vd0f6kw9sw4dxyie5cy9fa unique (name)
```

Except that SQLite [does not seem to support ALTER requests modifying constraints on tables](https://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html).

So my question is : Is there a way to literally indicate Hibernate to set that uniqueness constraint on table creation? What would be the best way to do it?

I can ensure uniqueness easily later on via code, but I'd rather use the power of the database if I can.

I should add that this is for a personal small application so so far I'm using the `update` setting for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` so Hibernate generates the SQL itself. I'm open to other methods but I'd rather avoid them if I can to reduce maintenance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna answer my own question given that it's not getting much traction :).

SQLite indeed does not support ALTER with constraints, and Hibernate does not (to my knowledge) offer a clean way to use custom SQL.
On top of this, [it is not recommended to use Hibernate: hbm2ddl.auto=update in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-production).

For those reasons, I decided to turn myself to [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) and write my own SQL. The good news is that adding Flyway provides my database migrations. The bad news is that it's one more dependency to maintain.

What I've done:

Added the flyway dependency in my build.gradle.kts

```
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:8.4.3")
```

Instantiated flyway before hibernate in my code, pointing to the same database:

```
    val flyway = Flyway
        .configure()
        .dataSource("jdbc:sqlite:test.db", null, null).load()
    flyway.migrate()
```

Added a handwritten SQL migration file in `resources/V1__Create_person_and_entries_table.sql`

```
create table Person
(
    id   integer primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null UNIQUE
);
```

Et voilà!

I wrote a blog post over [here](https://lengrand.fr/tips-and-tricks-using-hibernate-and-sqlite-with-kotlin/) with more details and some more reasons to use something like Flyway.

Comment: @jlegrand I was faced with exactly the same issue today. And i adopted your approach of manually fixing the migration script. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The Hibernate SQLiteDialect [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17245) you point to will be fixed in version 6.3.2. Hibernate will then stop emitting things like

```sql
ALTER TABLE some_table ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (some_column);
```

for SQLite.

The `unique` constraint should still be part of the table creation statement, though.