# there's no change in h2 table (objects are not created) made by jpa intellij

Tags: jpa, intellij-idea, h2

i wanna create objects with intellij (jpa) system,

but after i create objects,

there's no change in h2 console.

i expect that the objects are made like this, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IJNf.png)

(wanna make ITEM and MOVIE objects)

but what i got is this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEyTt.png)

these are the codes that i wrote.

```
package hellojpa;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Album extends Item{

    private String artist;
}
```

```
package hellojpa;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Book extends Item{
    private String author;
    private String isbn;
}
```

```
package hellojpa;

import org.hibernate.engine.internal.JoinSequence;
import org.hibernate.mapping.Join;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private int price;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

```
package hellojpa;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class JpaMain {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hello");

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();

        try{

            Movie movie = new Movie();
            movie.setDirector("aaaa");
            movie.setActor("bbbb");
            movie.setName("바람과 함께 사라지다");
            movie.setPrice(10000);

            tx.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            tx.rollback();
        } finally{
            em.close();
        }
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

```
package hellojpa;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Locker {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private  Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "locker")
    private Member member;
}
```

```
package hellojpa;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
        public class Member {
        @Id @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "MEMBER_ID")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "USERNAME")
        private String username;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "Team_ID",insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private Team team;

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name ="LOCKER_ID")
        private Locker locker;

       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "member")
       private List<MemberProduct> memberProducts = new ArrayList<>();

        public Long getId() {return id;}

        public void setId(Long id) {this.id = id;}

        public String getUsername() {return username;}

        public void setUsername(String username) {this.username = username;}


}
```

```
package hellojpa;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
public class MemberProduct {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="MEMBER_ID")
    private Member member;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    private Product product;

    private int count;
    private int price;
    private LocalDateTime orderDateTime;
}
```

```
package hellojpa;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Movie extends Item{

    private String director;
    private String actor;

    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public void setDirector(String director) {
        this.director = director;
    }

    public String getActor() {
        return actor;
    }

    public void setActor(String actor) {
        this.actor = actor;
    }


}
```

```
package hellojpa;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "product")
    private List<MemberProduct> memberProducts = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```
package hellojpa;

public enum RoleType {
    GUEST, USER, ADMIN
}
```

```
package hellojpa;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Team {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "TEAM_ID")
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID")
    private List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(Long id) {this.id = id;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public List<Member> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }
    public void setMembers(List<Member> members) {
        this.members = members;
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="hello">
        <properties>
            <!-- 필수 속성 -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>

            <!-- 옵션 -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="10"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the entityManager to `persist` your new entity. Therefore, jpa does not know about the new entity and nothing is saved.
Just add : `em.persist(movie);`

Answer (score 0):

The screenshots you provided, in combination with `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />`, suggests that you were not finished creating entity classes when you first run your application. Now if you use  `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create` and there is allready a schema present in your H2, it won't update the schema even though you added one or more entity classes.

The [community documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl) suggests that you use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update` in order to update the schema when the application is run.

Please note that, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-production) post, it is not safe to use `update` in a productive environment.

> Despite the best efforts of the Hibernate team, you simply cannot rely on automatic updates in production. Write your own patches, review them with DBA, test them, then apply them manually.
>
> Theoretically, if hbm2ddl update worked in development, it should work in production too. But in reality, it's not always the case.

I hope this helps.