# Spring Boot Flyway Dealing with different environments and restrictions in enterprises

Tags: spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

I am considering using Flyway for versioning database migrations for my Spring Boot API. I have been reading lots of article about it and I find that they talk mostly about setting it up which is great.

However, what I am concerned about is the typical enterprise environments where we have for example:

1. multiple deployment environments like PROD, TEST, DEV. We have no
   rights to view or modify PROD environments database for example.
   Delegating database migration to a tool/library in PROD environment does not sound reassuring and we are not allowed to do so, instead we provide scripts to DBAs to run them
2. we connect to different database vendors such as PostGres, Oracle,
   MSSQL, DB2 z/OS within the same API
3. in some cases, we will have to update already existing tables.  In
   other cases, we will have to create new tables

How does flyway deals with such cases?

Comment: Because of different database vendors, consider using Liquidbase, which is database agnostic migration tool, where scripts are written in xml form.

Comment: Is Flyway community dead?  Looks like no one is using it, no questions answered, not much going on on their github?

Answer (score 2):

2 & 3 are not a problem.

1 is, I will address it last.

**re (2) connecting to different dbs:**

flyway uses jdbc driver to connect to dbs and can connect to lots of em.

you can see some sample config here:

- https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/configuration-files-184127472.html
- https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/driver-184127498.html

**re (3) working with pre-existing dbs / tables:**

flyway is not an ORM. it doesn't map db state or table columns to code (classes etc) and doesn't try to match or sync code to db (which is something ORMs offer).

flyway only cares about the state in its managed [schema history table](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/migrations-184127470.html#Migrations-SchemaHistoryTable)

You don't have to create the migrations that happened "before now", you can just create the ones you need going forward and let flyway run them for you.

Note 1: you CAN create migrations in the past and tell flyway to skip them by setting a "baseline" or in other words "where to start"

Note 2: you can work with multiple dbs & multiple sql scripts by using multiple dirs (1 for each db) and running flyway multiple times, each time with the correct config for the db connection & scripts dir combo.

**re (1) enterprise env with no rights to manage dbs:**

It's not uncommon that devs are not allowed to write/change live envs (and sometime also other envs).

you will have to either:

- agree with your DB team (or whoever has access) that automation via tools is better than manual running scripts and show them how to use flyway (its not hard!!)
- use the deployment pipeline automation (CI/CD if exists) to run the migration.

In either case, you need some cooperation and buy-in from whoever has credentials/access. If you don't have that then there's no way going forward and you're stuck with how they want to work.

Comment: Thank you.  No way to generate SQL scripts that need to be run and give them to DBAs?

Comment: you wanto generate sql scripts? flyway doesn't do that.
it can run code instead of sql scripts if thats interesting to you, and from code you can do and use whatever you want. but then you definitely need to show DBAs how to run flyway (its no longer plain sql).

you can use Liquibase, as suggested before, if you wanto decsribe your migrations using xml and from that let it generate sqls.

Comment: Thanks, yes i need to generate SQL for DBAs for review and applying to database in production environments as devs do not have access to these

Comment: Thank you.  Given that Flyway does not support DB2 Z/OS and does not support feature to generate SQL scripts for review by DBAs before the migration is executed, it does not seem to be an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with Flyway Teams doing all these. I'm using it myself with 2 and 3 in your list. You can run Flyway easily in a script so that each time it runs, it uses a different JDBC connection. To get around problem 1, Flyway Teams has a feature called 'Dry Run' that allows it to generate a single script rather than execute a series of migrations. this script will maintain the flyway schema table when executed against PROD. Yes, if the DBAs just want a synch script rather than a chain of migrations, the dry run script will please them

Comment: Thank you.  I am interested in Flyway community which does not seem to provide a way to generate migration scripts (SQL scripts) for review with DBAs.  In addition, I find that Flyway does not support DB2 Z/OS which is what we use.  it supports only LUW version of DB2.