# Spring Boot Liquibase versioned database migration - dealing with different environments, db vendors and database credentials

Tags: spring-boot, database-migration, liquibase

I am considering using Liquibase for versioning database migrations for my Spring Boot API. I have been watching some videos about it before considering it and I find that they talk mostly about setting it and that is great.

But what I am concerned about is the typical enterprise environments where we have for example:

1. multiple deployment environments like PROD, TEST, DEV.  We have no rights to view or touch PROD environments database for example.  Delegating database migration, in for example PROD environment, sounds dangerous to me.
2. we connect to different database vendors such as PostGres, Oracle, MSSQL, DB2 within the same API
3. in some cases, we will have to work on already existing tables, in
   other cases, we will have to create new tables

How does Liquibase deals with such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you can use [generate-sql](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/generate-sql-update-schemas.html) to generate sql's that needs to be executed and then DBAs could run those sql commands
2. if there is something specific for some db vendor, you can create a specific `changeSet` with attribute `dbms`. Search for [dbms here](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/changeset.html)
3. you should be more specific about issue here. You can use [preconditions](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/preconditions.html) to check whether given script should be executed or not

Comment: Thank you.  Regarding #1, the issue is that we are not allowed to do any changes on PROD database, so no tool can automate changes on that.  It has to go through DBA.  So, I am not sure how to handle that?

Comment: I've modified my answer, hope that helps

Comment: I have one more question:  I want to separate migrations for new features vs migrations for fixes.  So, I would have "migration" folder and "migration_fix" folder or so.  Can that be handled by Liquibase?  Thanks

Comment: you can use [include](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/include.html). So just use one master changelog and from it include whatever you want. Keep in mind that it should be include chronologically. Oh and use [logicalfilepath](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/logicalfilepath.html) it will save you a headache in future.