# How to keep database content between consecutive runs of a Google App Engine app?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a Java / Spring app running on the standard environment. Every time I deploy it to App Engine, the postgres database I'm using is reset. How to prevent that?

My application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:///***

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

My app.yaml:

```
runtime: java17
instance_class: F1

automatic_scaling:
  max_idle_instances: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to chage your [`ddl-auto`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) config to:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

or

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

These are the options for `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`:

- `none`:  No database Schema initialization
- `create`:  Drops and creates the schema at the application startup. With this option, all your data will be gone on each startup.
- `create-drop`: Creates schema at the startup and destroys the schema on context closure. Useful for unit tests.
- `validate`:  Only checks if the Schema matches the Entities. If the schema doesn’t match, then the application startup will fail. *Makes no changes to the database*.
- `update`:  Updates the schema only if necessary. For example, If a new field was added in an entity, then it will simply alter the table for a new column *without destroying the data*

However, [`hibernate.ddl-auto`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional) **should usually not be used in production** ([check this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-production)).